# How can I check through command-line the computer form(Desktop, notebook or All-in-one)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, command-line, shell-script

For a very specific reason I need to check the computer form factor(Desktop, Notebook or All-in-one) remotelly, using a command  through the command-prompt, powershell or vbs(Windows 7/8 systems).

There is any way to do such thing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: easiest solution teamviewer http://www.pcworld.com/article/248991/how_to_log_in_to_your_pc_remotely_with_teamviewer.html

Comment: I didn't answer because teamviewer isn't exactly **command through the command-prompt, powershell or vbs** but will do the job and so easy to setup

Comment: The only way I can think of doing this would be to do a lookup on the system model although this would require more than just the command line. Use `wmic csproduct get name` to get the system model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

save it as info.vbs
go to script location from command prompt and type info.vbs , press enter

```
 strComputer = "."
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
        & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
    Set colChassis = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
        ("Select * from Win32_SystemEnclosure")
    For Each objChassis in colChassis
        For  Each strChassisType in objChassis.ChassisTypes
            Select Case strChassisType
                Case 1
                    Wscript.Echo "Other"
                Case 2
                    Wscript.Echo "Unknown"
                Case 3
                    Wscript.Echo "Desktop"
                Case 4
                    Wscript.Echo "Low Profile Desktop"
                Case 5
                    Wscript.Echo "Pizza Box"
                Case 6
                    Wscript.Echo "Mini Tower"
                Case 7
                    Wscript.Echo "Tower"
                Case 8
                    Wscript.Echo "Portable"
                Case 9
                    Wscript.Echo "Laptop"
                Case 10
                    Wscript.Echo "Notebook"
                Case 11
                    Wscript.Echo "Handheld"
                Case 12
                    Wscript.Echo "Docking Station"
                Case 13
                    Wscript.Echo "All-in-One"
                Case 14
                    Wscript.Echo "Sub-Notebook"
                Case 15
                    Wscript.Echo "Space Saving"
                Case 16
                    Wscript.Echo "Lunch Box"
                Case 17
```

Comment: +1 for Lunch Box and Pizza Box » [Win32_SystemEnclosure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394474(v=vs.85).aspx) - PS: `"\root\cimv2"` <?? Doesn't work for me, is there something to edit?

Comment: Problem solved with your solution. Thank you very much.